# Error C2665 'OdlRead': None of the 28 overloads could convert all the argument types

Tags: c++

I'm currently switching over a project from VS 2003 to VS 2019 and I'm having an issue with this particular set of code.

```
inline ODLBOOL OdlRead(ODLSerialize &dat, ODLStream *pStream)
{ return dat.Read(pStream); }
inline ODLBOOL OdlWrite(const ODLSerialize &dat, ODLStream *pStream)
{ return dat.Write(pStream); }
 
template <typename T>
inline ODLBOOL OdlRead(T * dat, ODLITEMCOUNT size, ODLStream *pStream)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (!OdlRead( dat[i], pStream))
            return ODLFALSE;
    }
    return ODLTRUE;
}
template <typename T>
inline ODLBOOL OdlWrite(const T * dat, ODLITEMCOUNT size, ODLStream *pStream)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (!OdlWrite(dat[i], pStream))
            return ODLFALSE;
    }
    return ODLTRUE;
}
```

The error is being called on this line

```
if (!OdlRead( dat[i], pStream))
```

I tried following [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2665?view=msvc-160) but to no avail.

The errors are:

```
4>C:\Users\akeem\Downloads\AVAOnline\AVAOnline\ava.dev\Server\Library\GateNet\GNDataSerialize.h(72,1): error C2665: 'OdlRead': none of the 28 overloads could convert all the argument types
4>C:\Users\akeem\Downloads\AVAOnline\AVAOnline\ava.dev\Server\External\RXNerve\RXNerveBase\Encode.h(55,13): message : could be 'BOOL OdlRead(RXNERVE_ADDR_TYPE &,IGNStreamEx *)'
4>C:\Users\akeem\Downloads\AVAOnline\AVAOnline\ava.dev\Server\External\RXNerve\RXNerveBase\Encode.h(30,13): message : or       'BOOL OdlRead(RXNERVE_ADDRESS &,IGNStreamEx *)'
4>C:\Users\akeem\Downloads\AVAOnline\AVAOnline\ava.dev\Server\External\RXNerve\RXNerveBase\Encode.h(9,16): message : or       'BOOL OdlRead(LPGNBUF,IGNStreamEx *)'
4>C:\Users\akeem\Downloads\AVAOnline\AVAOnline\ava.dev\Server\Library\GateNet\GNDataSerialize.h(62,16): message : or       'BOOL OdlRead(IGNSerializeEx &,IGNStreamEx *)'
4>C:\Users\akeem\Downloads\AVAOnline\AVAOnline\ava.dev\Server\Library\GateNet\GNDataSerialize.h(55,1): message : or       'BOOL OdlRead(double &,IGNStreamEx *)'
4>C:\Users\akeem\Downloads\AVAOnline\AVAOnline\ava.dev\Server\Library\GateNet\GNDataSerialize.h(54,1): message : or       'BOOL OdlRead(float &,IGNStreamEx *)'
4>C:\Users\akeem\Downloads\AVAOnline\AVAOnline\ava.dev\Server\Library\GateNet\GNDataSerialize.h(53,1): message : or       'BOOL OdlRead(unsigned __int64 &,IGNStreamEx *)'
4>C:\Users\akeem\Downloads\AVAOnline\AVAOnline\ava.dev\Server\Library\GateNet\GNDataSerialize.h(52,1): message : or       'BOOL OdlRead(unsigned int &,IGNStreamEx *)'
4>C:\Users\akeem\Downloads\AVAOnline\AVAOnline\ava.dev\Server\Library\GateNet\GNDataSerialize.h(51,1): message : or       'BOOL OdlRead(unsigned long &,IGNStreamEx *)'
4>C:\Users\akeem\Downloads\AVAOnline\AVAOnline\ava.dev\Server\Library\GateNet\GNDataSerialize.h(50,1): message : or       'BOOL OdlRead(unsigned short &,IGNStreamEx *)'
4>C:\Users\akeem\Downloads\AVAOnline\AVAOnline\ava.dev\Server\Library\GateNet\GNDataSerialize.h(49,1): message : or       'BOOL OdlRead(unsigned char &,IGNStreamEx *)'
4>C:\Users\akeem\Downloads\AVAOnline\AVAOnline\ava.dev\Server\Library\GateNet\GNDataSerialize.h(48,1): message : or       'BOOL OdlRead(__int64 &,IGNStreamEx *)'
4>C:\Users\akeem\Downloads\AVAOnline\AVAOnline\ava.dev\Server\Library\GateNet\GNDataSerialize.h(47,1): message : or       'BOOL OdlRead(int &,IGNStreamEx *)'
4>C:\Users\akeem\Downloads\AVAOnline\AVAOnline\ava.dev\Server\Library\GateNet\GNDataSerialize.h(46,1): message : or       'BOOL OdlRead(long &,IGNStreamEx *)'
4>C:\Users\akeem\Downloads\AVAOnline\AVAOnline\ava.dev\Server\Library\GateNet\GNDataSerialize.h(45,1): message : or       'BOOL OdlRead(short &,IGNStreamEx *)'
4>C:\Users\akeem\Downloads\AVAOnline\AVAOnline\ava.dev\Server\Library\GateNet\GNDataSerialize.h(44,1): message : or       'BOOL OdlRead(char &,IGNStreamEx *)'
4>C:\Users\akeem\Downloads\AVAOnline\AVAOnline\ava.dev\Server\Library\GateNet\GNDataSerialize.h(72,1): message : while trying to match the argument list '(T, IGNStreamEx *)'
4>        with
4>        [
4>            T=WCHAR
4>        ]
4>C:\Users\akeem\Downloads\AVAOnline\AVAOnline\ava.dev\Server\Project\CMS\odlCMSMessage.cpp(34): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'BOOL OdlRead<WCHAR>(T *,WORD,IGNStreamEx *)' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            T=WCHAR
4>        ]
```

Comment: If you know that `dat` will be an array of `ODLSerialize` objects, why not take the parameter as such instead of using a template?

Comment: What are you instantiating the template with, and what is it that has 28 overloads?

Comment: @scohe001 Consider arrays of different derived classes.

Comment: @molb maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't that still work if you passed in an array of `ODLSerialize` references? With a template you have no guarantee that you're looking at a derived type (unlike C#, where you can specify what the template will look like)

Comment: @scohe001 There is no such thing as an array of references.

Comment: @molb an array of pointers then, if you prefer. Or an `std::vector` of references if OP feels comfortable with that switch.

Comment: @scohe001 An array of pointers is of no use if you want to work with arrays (or vectors) of instances, not of pointers, or don't want to discard type information.

Comment: This isnt my code, this is a game's source code